# Why am I receiving the following Chainlink error: cannot estimate gas

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I am trying to follow the Chainlink VRF tutorial found here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/intermediates-tutorial/ with hardhat and am running into this issue when calling the rollDice function:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","method":"estimateGas","transaction":{"from":"0x014Da1D627E6ceB555975F09D26B048644382Ac6","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x9502f900"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x9502f90e"},"to":"0x5887946875A01D1BB79d6Fb357BceeA5A0096D2e","data":"0xdd02d9e5000000000000000000000000014da1d627e6ceb555975f09d26b048644382ac6","type":2,"accessList":null}}, tx={"data":"0xdd02d9e5000000000000000000000000014da1d627e6ceb555975f09d26b048644382ac6","to":{},"from":"0x014Da1D627E6ceB555975F09D26B048644382Ac6","type":2,"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x9502f90e"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x9502f900"},"nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=abstract-signer/5.5.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/matt/Desktop/hardhat/randomDay/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:225:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/matt/Desktop/hardhat/randomDay/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:237:20)
    at /Users/matt/Desktop/hardhat/randomDay/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/src.ts/index.ts:301:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 7)
```

I am able to deploy to the Kovan testnet, I was able to verify the contract, and I have sent the contract LINK tokens, but am still running into the issue. The contract can be viewed here: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x7b72d80670512c87605ab8ac7e6113fda9c57de4#code

I am using version 0.8 of the Chainlink Contracts.

**RandomDay.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract RandomDay is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    uint256 private constant ROLL_IN_PROGRESS = 42;
    bytes32 private s_keyHash;
    uint256 private s_fee;

    mapping(bytes32 => address) private s_rollers;
    mapping(address => uint256) private s_results;

    event DiceRolled(bytes32 indexed requestId, address indexed roller);
    event DiceLanded(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint256 indexed result);

    constructor(address vrfCoordinator, address link, bytes32 keyHash, uint256 fee) VRFConsumerBase(vrfCoordinator, link) {
        s_keyHash = keyHash;
        s_fee = fee;
   
    }

    function rollDice (address roller) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= s_fee, "Not enough LINK to pay fee");
        require(s_results[roller] == 0, "Already rolled");
        requestId = requestRandomness(s_keyHash, s_fee);
        s_rollers[requestId] = roller;
        s_results[roller] = ROLL_IN_PROGRESS;
        emit DiceRolled(requestId, roller);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomness (bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        uint256 dayOfWeek = (randomness % 7) + 1;
        s_results[s_rollers[requestId]] = dayOfWeek;
        emit DiceLanded(requestId, dayOfWeek);
    }

    function weekday (address player) public view returns (string memory) {
        require(s_results[player] != 0, "Dice not rolled");
        require(s_results[player] != ROLL_IN_PROGRESS, "Roll in progress");
        return getWeekdayName(s_results[player]);
    }

    function getWeekdayName (uint256 id) private pure returns (string memory) {
        string[7] memory weekdays = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        return weekdays[id - 1];
    }

}
```

**hardhat.config.js**

```
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */

 require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
 require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")

 const ALCHEMY_API_KEY = "*************************";
 const ROPSTEN_PRIVATE_KEY = "*********************";
 
 module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.8.9",
   networks: {
     kovan: {
       url: `https://eth-kovan.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
       accounts: [`0x${ROPSTEN_PRIVATE_KEY}`],
       gas: 2700000000,
       maxFeePerGas: 30000000000,
     }
   },
   etherscan: {
    // Your API key for Etherscan
    // Obtain one at https://etherscan.io/
    apiKey: "****************************"
  }
 };
```

**deploy.js**

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  
    console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);
  
    console.log("Account balance:", (await deployer.getBalance()).toString());
  
    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("RandomDay");
    const token = await Token.deploy("0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088", "0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9", "0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4", "100000000000000000");
  
    console.log("Token address:", token.address); 
  }
  
  main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
```

**quickRun.js**

```
var ethers = require('ethers');
var provider = ethers.providers.getDefaultProvider('kovan');
var address  = '0x7b72d80670512c87605aB8aC7E6113Fda9c57de4';
var abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"vrfCoordinator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"link","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"keyHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"fee","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"requestId","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"result","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DiceLanded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"requestId","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"roller","type":"address"}],"name":"DiceRolled","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"requestId","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"randomness","type":"uint256"}],"name":"rawFulfillRandomness","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"roller","type":"address"}],"name":"rollDice","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"requestId","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"player","type":"address"}],"name":"weekday","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
var privateKey = '*******************************';
var wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
var contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, wallet);

var sendPromise = contract.rollDice('0x014Da1D627E6ceB555975F09D26B048644382Ac6');

sendPromise.then(function(transaction){
  console.log(transaction);
});
```

Comment: Did you set the constructor arguments correctly for the Kovan network? I tested your contract as you posted it in this post on Kovan and called the function properly (meaning the Solidity code is fine). However, when I interact with your deployed code on Etherscan it doesn't work (this also rules out it being a hardhat issue).

Comment: Did you fund your contract with LINK? I don't see you running the fund-link function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the addresses are off:

Constructor Arguments of your contract:
-----Decoded View---------------
Arg [0] : vrfCoordinator (address): 0xa36085f69e2889c224210f603d836748e7dc0088
Arg [1] : link (address): 0xdd3782915140c8f3b190b5d67eac6dc5760c46e9
Arg [2] : keyHash (bytes32): 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4
Arg [3] : fee (uint256): 100000000000000000

Via Chainlinks Docs:

LINK    0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
VRF Coordinator 0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9
Key Hash    0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4
Fee 0.1 LINK

Switched Link and VRF are probably the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

9 out of 10 is because you passed something wrong in the constructor or something in the contructor is not initialized propertly. this kind of things aren't detected by compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

I solved it in this way.

1. Create a new directory totally empty: /blabla/createsmartaccount_dir.
2. Create these 2 files inside it.

/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/index.js

/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/package.json

3. Run the commands

npm install

node ./index.js

```
#/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/index.js

const { ethers } = require( 'ethers')
const { EthersAdapter } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const Safe = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { SafeFactory } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { SafeAccountConfig } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { ContractNetworksConfig } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')

const execute = async () => {
    const RPC_URL='https://rpc2.sepolia.org'
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL)
    
    
    
    // Initialize signers
    //metamask wallet and privatekey
    //0x967c1CF5d91f3738c969c76EB4bDddA6da4183c1
    const signerWallet = 
new ethers.Wallet("ca46xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", provider)

    const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ethers, signerOrProvider: signerWallet})
    
    const chainId = await ethAdapter.getChainId()
    console.log(`ChainId: ${chainId}`)

    
  
    
    const safeVersion = '1.3.0'
    const isL1SafeMasterCopy = false
    const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter: ethAdapter })



    const safeAccountConfig = {
        threshold: 1, // Have to be >= 1 && <= totalOwners
        owners: ["0x967xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
        eth_estimateGas:30000,
    }
    console.log("Start Deploying Safe");



    
    
    //This Safe is tied to owner 1 because the factory was initialized with an 
    //adapter that had owner 1 as the signer. 
  
    const safeSdkOwner1 = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig })

    const safeAddress = safeSdkOwner1.getAddress()

    console.log(`Safe deployed at: ${safeAddress}`)  
}
execute();
```

```
#/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/package.json

{
  "dependencies": {
    "@safe-global/api-kit": "^1.0.1",
    "@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^0.1.1",
    "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^1.10.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "5.7.2"
  }
}
```

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150579/periodic-failure-when-attempting-to-create-gnosis-safe-via-safe-global-protocol/150771#150771